# Creating a Drupal view with an RSS feed

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, rss, drupal-views

I am very new to Drupal and I need a bit of help. I am working with Drupal 6 (because that is what the site uses).

I was asked to make a View that would display a RSS feed of certain parts of the website and I don't understand how to do this. I know how to create a View and that it must be set as a "feed". But I am not clear about what to do from here. From the examples I have seen (and not entirely understood), it seems you might need to to modify the arguements or fields, but in which way?

Also, what exactly does the "attach to" in the feed settings do?

Answer (score 5):

You will want to create a view, and add a display of type feed using row style: node.
The default behavior will assume you want to include all fields on the node in the feed.

However, you can control the fields that are included in the feed by going to Content Management > [Your content type] > Display fields > RSS.  From here there are checkboxes which allow you to select fields for exclusion when being displayed as part of an RSS feed.

The "attach to" setting allows you to select a page or block view on which to display an RSS icon that links to this feed.

Depending on the content you want to include in the feed, you will want to set a filter, most likely on node: type, and node: published.